# Httpful JSON inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, httpful

I've been trying for 3 days to get PHP to show the ID from this test JSON using PHP and httpful.

Anyone have any ideas as i've tried loads of different combinations and even tried created a handler to decode as an array... I just suck at PHP ?

```
// Make a request to the GitHub API with a custom
// header of "X-Trvial-Header: Just as a demo".
<?php
include('\httpful.phar');

$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
$response = Httpful\Request::get($url)
    ->expectsJson()
    ->send();
echo "{$response[0]['id']}";

?>
```

[My output... still nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4pRS.jpg)

Comment: sorry ignore my last comment!! i have deleted it

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly indexing the return value.

The response is a mixed value. So you should do something like below to get what you are looking for.

```
<?php
include('\httpful.phar');

$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
$response = Httpful\Request::get($url)
    ->expectsJson()
    ->send();

echo $response->body[0]->id;

?>
```

Comment: thanks, when i tried that combination i had id as ['id'] and it didnt work !

Comment: You don't need to index it with `['id']` because its an object, you should use `->id` as I posted above @HaaggisAlliLove